# the drop menus disappeard in wordpress website

Tags: html, css, wordpress, plugins

the menu in this website that i'm working on recently was broken, the drop down doesn't work & the navigation bar in the mobile version doesn't work as well. i checked the code it was the same. and i can't try to disable plugins it would be too risky. is anyone familiar with this issue?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DvIkw.png)

the arrows suddenly disappeard and the working menu only exists in the cart page.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BK7tZ.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!, Please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), then look at the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)